# jQuery validation in JSP

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp

For my servlet Java program, I have used JSP and used jQuery client side validation for `.xls` for uploading a file. It's running successfully for all the user but one of our users is getting problems while uploading a `.xls` file. The program is showing an alert message and does not allow to upload a file. We also checked browser compatibility.

Questions:

1. What would be the reason?
2. Is it adding extra char with extension `.xls`? If yes, then what would be solution?
3. Is it a network issue? If yes, then what would be solution?

This is the code:

```
function dosearch(){

    var reportFile = document.form1.reportFile.value;

    if(reportFile==null || reportFile==''){

        $("#span_filename").show();

        if(!window.console)
        {
            window.console = {log: function(){}};
        }else{
        console.log("file name is not valid"+reportFile);
        }

    }else if(reportFile.substring(reportFile.indexOf(".")+1)!="xls"){

        alert("Please make sure the uploaded file is an excel file");


        if(!window.console)
        {
            window.console = {log: function(){}};
        }else{
    console.log("invalid file format or might be its adding extra name or extension name with file , "+reportFile);             
        }

    }else if(confirm('Do you want to upload now?')){

        form1.bt1.disabled=true;

        $("#pro").show();

    document.form1.action='catalog?module=PayrollResultUpload&cmd=doUpload';

        document.form1.submit();

    }
```

Comment: Without code its difficult to tell a solution. Please post the validation what you have done.

Comment: Check the console for any JS error, Also Check the server log if there is any other error, Kindly give more details by example. To help debug your problem.

Comment: @Amit Bhardawaj Whats the alert message shown?

Comment: @san krish I am getting same message that what i have define in the alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done some RND test in browser console there, I have got the exact problem , its getting extra dot(.) before the file but that dot(.) was not in the file it was in the client systems folder structure i.e. C:\ads.test\file\FILE_NAME_HERE.xls . So, I have used lastIndexOf()  method instead of indexOf() method . now it running fine without any problem.

@Thiamath , gratitude for your valuable information for me,and be in a part for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, seems that you are only validating xls extension. To improve this, for example to check xlsx extension, I suggest you to make a regex pattern check.
Change the line:

```
}else if(reportFile.substring(reportFile.indexOf(".")+1)!="xls"){
```

with this other version:

```
}else if(reportFile.substring(reportFile.indexOf(".")+1).match(/^xls.?$/i)){
```

This will check if there is a character at the end of the extension.
Regarding network issues... You can check the connection with an AJAX worker polling connection regularly and advising the user if there is no connection, but I think its too complicated for this case. Better tell the user to try to upload later ;)

Comment: @ thiamath  hi i want to do validation against .xls only

Comment: @AmitBhardwaj But if the problem is that user is sending a file with other extension than xls. The expected result is an alert. So... where is the problem then? Do you want to change the extension in the JS code?

Comment: @AmitBhardwaj Sorry if you felt I'm not taking your problem seriously. I grant you i'm serious on this. But I'm a little confused... What of the alerts you put in the code is the one the user is reporting?

Comment: hi @Thiamath its more valuable for me that what u have repleted to me in answer.I will let you know in detail. In the code I have done client side validation with only one extension type that is .xls file and I want client should upload only .xls extension. now, think  we have 100 clients and they are using our products. where 99 clients are able to upload .xls file successfully but the problem is there, our one client is not able to upload .xls file . that's why I am getting confuse.

Comment: @AmitBhardwaj I see. First of all should be to know which of the alerts you implemented in your validation raises to the user that have problems to upload. If the problem is with the extension, then seems to be a human-error problem and your user is sending a invalid extension. If the user is not getting any alert but the upload still fails, then it can be a network error... maybe a firewall or proxy is blocking the upload but allowing navigation.

Comment: u r correct , I also thought its a human-error problem to uploading a file  and i have asked the same file from the client what the client is uploading the .xls file . but when i tried it is working successful from my system and uploading the file in database. but when the client is trying from there system its not uploading .xls file. and giving alert message that what i have written alert message on the ave code example. i thinks its not a code problem might be some other problem  if it is other then what & what should be a solution.

Comment: @AmitBhardwaj What is the alert message reported by the user?

Comment: if(reportFile.substring(reportFile.indexOf(".")+1)!="xls"){
//this alert message i am getting  ......                                                
        alert("Please make sure the uploaded file is an excel file");

Comment: @AmitBhardwaj Sorry for the delay. If that is the alert, then something MUST be wrong with the filename. Human error is on course. Try the code I gave you but remove this: `.?` in the regular expression. This code should perform matches with upper-lower case also and .XLS will be also accepted.

Comment: ok thanks allot for ur valuable suggestion on this problem I will try it and get back on this, once again thanks allot to u.